# GSON recursively decode map keys

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to use GSON to decode an array of maps in which the keys are not Strings. I know that the JSON type does not allow for objects to be used as keys, so I was hoping it is possible to have GSON work recursively to decode Strings.

**Java**

```
public class Reader {
    static class Key {
        int a;
        int b;
    }
    static class Data {
        HashMap<Key, Integer> map;
    }


    public static void read() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String x = "[{\"map\": { \"{\\\"a\\\": 0, \\\"b\\\": 0}\": 1 }}]";
        Data[] y = gson.fromJson(x, Data[].class);
    }
}
```

**JSON example**

```
[
    {
        "map": {
            "{\"a\": 0, \"b\": 0}": 1
        }
    }
]
```

What I would like to achieve here, is that the string `"{\"a\": 0, \"b\": 0}"` is decoded by GSON to an object of type `Key` with both members set to 0. Then, that object could be used to fill out the HashMap of the Data class.

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with custom `JsonDeserializer`. With a custom deserializer you can decide howto deserialize this class `Key`. Implement it somewhere, inline example below:

```
public JsonDeserializer<Key> keyDs = new JsonDeserializer<Key>() {
    private final Gson gson = new Gson(); 
    @Override
    public Key deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                               JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        // This will be valid JSON
        String keyJson = json.getAsString();
        // use another Gson to parse it, 
        // otherwise you will have infinite recursion
        Key key = gson.fromJson(keyJson, Key.class);
        return key;
    }
};
```

Register it with `GsonBuilder`, create `Gson` and deserialize:

```
Data[] mapPojos = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Key.class, ds).create()
            .fromJson(x, Data[].class);
```