# How to convert pojo to json using gson with certain String fields already having json in them?

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

I have a pojo as shown below. I have a toString method in it which is responsible for converting it to json data. As you can see I am using gson in that toString method.

```
// removed setters for brevity
public class User {

    private String name, email, password;

    // This information field is already a json as mentioned below
    private String information;

    public User(String name, String email, String password, String information) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.information = information;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
        return gson.toJson(this);
    }
```

The problem is that out of all these fields, my `information` field will already be a json string. In my main program, I am filling this User object like this.

```
// filled it with random info, but I will get this from someplace else
String info = "{  \r\n" + 
        "   \"street_address\":{  \r\n" + 
        "      \"type\":\"string\"\r\n" + 
        "   },\r\n" + 
        "   \"city\":{  \r\n" + 
        "      \"type\":\"string\"\r\n" + 
        "   },\r\n" + 
        "   \"state\":{  \r\n" + 
        "      \"type\":\"string\"\r\n" + 
        "   }\r\n" + 
        "}";

User user = new User("John", "Doe", "password", info);

return user.toString();
```

This is the output that I am getting.

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "email": "Doe",
  "password": "password",
  "information": "{\r\n    \"street_address\": { \"type\": \"string\" },\r\n    \"city\":           { \"type\": \"string\" },\r\n    \"state\":          { \"type\": \"string\" }\r\n}"
}
```

What I want is that last `information` field to `also` be properly formatted meaning this is what I am expecting for this example.

```
{  
   "name":"John",
   "email":"Doe",
   "password":"password",
   "information":{  
      "street_address":{  
         "type":"string"
      },
      "city":{  
         "type":"string"
      },
      "state":{  
         "type":"string"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: would it be okay if i make information field transient? or change the data type of string to Object?

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52541220/6413377) helps you.